# why when i use div.load() of jquery, my whole page reload instead of just reload the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use div.load(), but instead the div loaded, the whole page reload. I just want to refresh the div#trial part when click submit without refresh the whole page.
Here's the code:

```
    <form  method="post">
                Date <?php select_date();  ?>
                 Exercise 
                <select name="exercise" style="font-size:15px; height:30px; line-height:30px;"> 
                    <option value="-1">All</option>
                    <option value="0">Arm Supination</option>
                    <option value="1">Arm Pronation</option>
                    <option value="2">Elbow Flexion</option>
                    <option value="3">Elbow Raise</option>
                    <option value="4">Shoulder Flexion</option>
                    <option value="5">Shoulder Abduction</option>
                </select> 
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
            </form>

    <div class="grid_5 mb_50 mt_50" id="trial" style="overflow:scroll; height:400px;}">
        <?php display_ses(); ?>
    </div>


   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function (){ 
   $('#submit').click(function(){
    $('div.#trial').load('Patient_daily.php div.#trial');
    });

   });
   </script>
```

Comment: I don't think `'div.#trial'` is a valid jQuery selector

Answer (score 0):

That's because clicking your submit button submits the form, which causes the browser to leave the current page. To prevent the natural action of the button, use `preventDefault`.

```
$('#submit').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('div.#trial').load('Patient_daily.php div.#trial');
});
```

Comment: Or, just use an `<input type="button">`, when that's really what you want

Comment: Nothing in formData ever gets submitted though and selectors are likely to fail

Comment: Thank you very much! I use submit because I need to use the data selected to connect database and retrieve information from database. The event.preventDefault() worked but it can not pass parameter and finish the retrieve part! Anyway, thank you very much!